# "Remove wiki" does not register in revision history

Tags: bug, status-completed, moderator-tools, community-wiki, revisions-list

I removed CW status from [this answer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/103501/thoughts-on-development-using-virtual-machines/103504#103504). Before I did that, the revision history showed that the post was made Community Wiki by the poster.

Now that I removed CW, the revision history does not show either that the post was ever CW or that I cleared the status.

Comment: Super-ninja mod powers.

Comment: You altered the timestream. Stop doing that.

Comment: @mmyers Sorry. :(

Comment: Looks like currently, if you remove wiki, we record a `wiki removed` but the original `made wiki` is gone. If you remake wiki, the remove notice remains, and a new `made wiki` is added. Removing wiki again removes both those items and adds a new one. Looks like we only keep the data directly on the post and don't have history on it. Perhaps we should.

Comment: @Oded it just caused another [case of confusion](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/208453/152859) - think I should start bug report?

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd - dunno. CW is rare enough that it is an anomaly by itself. Not sure this is worth our time to sort out.

Comment: Well, now that you're a dev, Anna, can't you just fix this yourself?

Comment: Half of this was fixed about a year ago, @Shadow - we made the "mod removes wiki" entries public. The other half... Well, probably need to think a bit about what *should* happen there: it's not like we actually treat de-wikied posts as though they were wikied during that period.

Comment: @Shog9 well, it's only part of what appears to be a [bigger problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/230988/undoing-community-wiki-as-a-moderator-rewrites-history) anyway.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Hah. I ... forgot I even posted this. Funny how things change over the course of a few years. ;)

Comment: All good Anna, I sometimes post something only to find I already asked this exact thing (usually a feature request) in the past! :-)

Answer (score 1):

Apparently we started recording/showing this at some point. Using [my own example](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/posts/103504/revisions):

[image]