# Strange revision note for Community Wiki

Tags: support, community-wiki, revisions-list

On a [recent post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/208393/212780), the [revision history](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/208393/revisions) states:

> **Post Made Community Wiki** by question having more than 30 answers

Now, I totally understand why it was made wiki, and realize that it **now** has over 30 answers, but it didn't at the time. From what I can tell, it was made CW when it was turned into a contest (for obvious reasons).

Is the note one of several default options, chosen because it was *expected* to get many answers? Normally when I see posts turned wiki for reasons like this, it's just given as `[made Community Wiki]` in the edit notes or something similar.

Just curious why the message isn't consistent with the timeline.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For some reason this "bug" is quite known behavior that was never fixed. Basically, the community wiki *reason* is calculated on the fly, not stored with the post. A user always causes the community wiki to occur, even for 30 answers (the person who posted the 30th answer) and edits (the person who made the edit that cause wikification). The system only looks at the additional criteria after the fact.

So whenever a question is community wiki and has more than 30 answers, the system will always list the reason as having had more than 30 answers, whether that was the actual cause of the wikification or not. Not ideal behavior, and I don't know what SE's *official* stance is on whether they want to fix it or not. Honestly, if they're not going to better maintain what caused the wikification, I'd rather just go back to the "made community wiki by *user*" and not have the other reasons at all.

Similarly, if the question was converted to wiki by having 30 answers and drops back below the 30 mark, the reason disappears and it shows the user who originally posted that 30th answer as having converted the question and its answers to community wiki.

Comment: Most likely Tim Post made it CW. Going to ask.

Comment: He did. I remember seeing his name on the note before it reached 30 answers.

Comment: That's a full scale bug then, in my humble opinion. Was it reported before?

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. The cause that is, not the effect

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd I only know about it because I had reported it in the Teacher's Lounge (I believe) and a Community Manager explained it to me. There are other posts about it floating around but I don't remember them.

Comment: *"So whenever a question is community wiki and has more than 30 answers, the system will always list the reason as having had more than 30 answers"* -- I don't think so. At least, not always. See [comments here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/106569/could-the-made-community-wiki-by-entry-in-the-revision-list-show-the-actua/107555#107555). (Ah, or maybe you're right: those Super User examples are border cases, due to deleted answers. The threshold is 15 on Super User, by the way.)

Comment: Today, it failed on all (now: 6) answers [on a CW question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/213769/work-is-hard-lets-color-the-walls), where in each answer the author of that very answer [is shown](http://i.stack.imgur.com/67EF3.png) in "Post Made Community Wiki by ..." Curious what will happen once that question reaches 30 answers.

Answer (score 2):

> Is the note one of several default options, chosen because it was expected to get many answers?

No, it usually says "Made Community Wiki by [username]"

I think the 30-answers trigger for autowikifying may have overwrote the previous revision history.

Comment: [You've been blamed too](http://i.stack.imgur.com/67EF3.png) ;-)