# Undoing community wiki as a moderator rewrites history

Tags: bug, moderator-tools, community-wiki

Moderators have the ability to make a post community wiki and also to remove the community wiki status from any post. But there are several issues with how this is recorded in the revision history, the moderator-only post timeline (`/admin/posts/timeline/`) and the moderator action history (`/admin/history/`):

- The initial entry for manual conversion to CW shows the wrong message:

  > Post Made Community Wiki by Fabian♦ editing at least 10 times

  It should show that this was a moderator using their moderator power to make the post CW
- The entry in the revision history and in the post timeline indicating that a post was made CW is erased completely when the CW status is lifted again. There is no trace that the post was ever CW except for the entry indicating that the CW status was lifted.
- There is no entry at all generated in the moderator action history, even though this is a mod-only action and should probably be logged there.

Comment: Sounds familiar, not sure if dupe was already posted or just saw it mentioned in comments or chat.

Comment: Found [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/103942/remove-wiki-does-not-register-in-revision-history), it's only partially dupe though.