# Timeline is lacking an entry if a post is made community wiki again after the community wiki status was removed

Tags: bug, moderator-tools, community-wiki

Currently [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/364818/369802) is shown as being a community wiki post. There's no reason for it to be, so someone (not me) tried to remove the community wiki status of the post. This was logged in the timeline, which currently says:

[image]

There's no mention of it being 'made wiki' again after that. According to [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/315516/why-does-this-question-continue-to-show-as-community-wiki-even-though-a-moderat) and science done by [Ryan M and Andrew T.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/364828/369802), that is probably because re-adding the community wiki status doesn't create another timeline entry.

This is confusing, since I was thinking the button may have malfunctioned (see [my first revision](https://meta.stackexchange.com/revisions/364825/1)). Can this please be fixed, so moderators can know what happened and can act accordingly?

Comment: Well, according to the [reputation summary of the post](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fL1N0.png) it did work, for a while. Really weird.

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/230988/undoing-community-wiki-as-a-moderator-rewrites-history

Comment: I've already reported this problem: [Why does this question continue to show as Community Wiki, even though a moderator removed community wiki status?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/315516/why-does-this-question-continue-to-show-as-community-wiki-even-though-a-moderat). It seems that a moderator making it wiki again after it getting removed doesn't generate a history item.

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog You asked a support question, so I'm going to leave this one as the subsequent bug report then. Thanks for confirming it's not the button that's broken though!

Comment: This seems to be the result of some bug interbreeding, and various attempts to tweeze them apart: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/103942/282094 https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/208458/282094 https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/107555/282094

Answer (score 14):

It looks like the bug is that after the first instance of adding and removing Community Wiki status, additional Timeline entries aren't generated.

In order to reproduce the bug, [this (now deleted) post](https://android.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2652/327123) was converted to and from Community Wiki three times each (simulating a "war" between a user and a moderator over a post's Community Wiki status) with the assistance of a [helpful moderator](https://android.stackexchange.com/users/44325/andrew-t).  However, only the first conversion each way shows up, despite edits and comments occurring in between:

[image]